Several conditions in one Regex expression
I am trying to validate a .csv field that must be numeric. Regex for this is pretty straightforward. However, the field can have multiple numbers. In that case, they must be comma separated and the entire field must be enclosed in double quotes like this "23,567,1". I came up with this Regex to validate this
^\"\d+(,\d+)*\\"$

But how do I combine the two conditions in one Regex so that both value types - a single number and a coma separated double quoted string of numbers get accepted?

Are you aware of the | regex symbol?

Hi Scott, I feel a bit dumb because I have been using | so many times for string combinations like ^(?i)(PX|QC|HT)$ but for some reason my brain got frozen when I had to combine two expressions instead of string values. Lack of experience, ha?   :) Now I know. Thank you for pointing this out.

Use two patterns, one for a single number, and another for comma-separated numbers, and combine them as alternatives with |
^(?:\d+|"\d+(?:,\d+)+")$


Here is another idea, it possibly looks more complicated but I'm all for learning new things. It requires that the regular expression engine allows "conditional" (sub) expressions, not all do. The version used in Notepad++ does.
Rexegg Conditionals reference
^(")?\d+(?(1)(,\d+)+")$
So looking for an initial ", if it exists group 1 is assigned the ". The "?(1)" states that if group 1 has been set then the following (sub) expression MUST find 1 (or more) sequences of commas and numbers and finally followed by a closing ".

Thank you Terry, your solution works as well. And yes, conditional expressions look a bit more complex but I agree worth learning for cases when this approach makes more sense.
